# Select which satisfies at least N conditions from M available

Tags: sql, database, logic, discrete-mathematics

there is a question floated. It's set in basic SQL terms, but its nature is pure math (so maybe I should visit https://mathoverflow.net too).

I have a table in some theoretical database with 6 fields, all are numbers. Also we have basic conditions, such as Field_1 > Field_5, Field_4 = 3 etc., 7 conditions total. I need to write a select, which satisfies **at least** 4 of them.

Writing long select with many logical conditions such as *(cond_1 AND cond_2 AND cond_3 and cond_4) OR (...)* is not a way, because 4-combination from 7 elements is equal to 140, and one doesn't want to write so many conditions.

So how do I write a select in its simplified form?

Comment: What database are you using? Type and version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of doing it is to count 1 for each condition that the row satisfies and compare the sum to your target value:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable
WHERE (
          (CASE WHEN condition1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
          (CASE WHEN condition2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
          ...
          (CASE WHEN condition7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      ) >= 4
```

Note that this will require evaluating all the conditions for each row so you won't get a short-circuiting effect, but it's simple and maybe it has good enough performance for you.

If you're using MySQL you can write this in a much simpler way because a boolean result is equivalent to 0 or 1 so you don't need the CASE statements:

```
WHERE (condition1) + (condition2) + ... + (condition7) >= 4
```

Comment: It's not the problem of performance or database version, actually, question is theoretical, and should be done in pure SQL, not in its exstensions like PL/SQL, but I'd prefer Oracle instead. Thanks for broadened answer, by the way, it seems to be true, but Mike Burton was first.

Comment: Actually Mark was first by 15 seconds or so, and has the overall better answer, so you may as well mark his instead.

Comment: Ok, as you wish, but I have some doubts about both answers now. Aren't they providing ALL rows from table, IF 4 conditions are satisfied by any fields, instead of providing only ROWS, WHICH fields are satisfying at least 4 conditions?

Comment: @Chaotic_one: The WHERE clause applies to each row individually. Only the rows which satisfy four or more of the conditions are returned in the result set. That is I believe what you wanted.

Comment: Yeah, I got that when I was typing my doubts actually :) I'm running a test now and I'm sure that result will be brilliant. Thanks for great answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add the sum of the true conditions together, a la

```
CASE 
WHEN Field1 > Field5 THEN
    1
ELSE
    0
END
+
CASE
WHEN Field4 = 3 THEN
    1
ELSE
    0
END
+
etc
AS condition_sum
```

and filter on condition_sum > threshhold.  You could even put the nastiness of that sum-of-cases expression into a function for slightly more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest simply counting up how many conditions are satisfied. The particular syntax will depend on which database management engine you're using, but in MySQL it would look something like this:

```
SELECT things
FROM places
WHERE IF(cond_1, 1, 0) + IF(cond_2, 1, 0) + IF(cond_3, 1, 0) + IF(cond_4, 1, 0) + IF(cond_5, 1, 0) >= 4;
```